# Redirect isn't working and return whr error 0

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I make a `redirection` in a `controller`:

```
return Redirect("http://another.domainThanTheCurrentApllication.com/sso?token=token==");
```

And this controller is called by

```
$(document).on("click", ".rounded-button > a", function () {
            hideContent();
            $('#Content').load(this.href, function (response, status, xhr) {
                showContent();
                if (status == "error") {
                    var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
                    $("#cloudContent").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
                }
                cufonStyle();
            });
            return false;
        });
```

The partialView is OK, and the status is on "`error`". The message outputed in the partial placeholder is "`Sorry but there was an error: 0`", and there is no redirection.
There is no exception in the Redirection.

I tested the URL of the redirection, and it's work well in my browser.

Thanks to help me,

Comment: As you are calling controller action asynchronously it will not perform page redirection

Comment: @Satpal OK many thanks, but witch method can I call instead of the load?

Comment: I would suggest you to send url to client and then perform redirection using window.location.href

Comment: @Satpal, dirty method, isn't it?

Comment: Why its dirty? You are responding to Ajax call whether its success/failure and taking action accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method is used to fetch the data from the server and place into the matched element. Here you are completely defeating the aim of ajax and load() functionality.

Inside the click function you can redirect like this

```
 window.location.href = "http://another.domainThanTheCurrentApllication.com/sso?token=token=="
```

or else if you want to get redirect url from server

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
    url:this.href,
    success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
       window.location.href = data.url;
    }
```

and in controller

```
    return Json(new { url = "http://another.domainThanTheCurrentApllication.com/sso?token=token==" });
```